# jQuery each object selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble using the `$(this)` object inside an `.each()`..

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. This works, so its not critical, but I would like to know why it doesn't work with `$(this).on("click` instead of `$("#b_" + thumb_id).on("click"`

```js
//Create a flip button for each attached image.
$(".attached_preview").each(function(){
    var att_name = $(this).attr("data-name"), thumb_id = $(this).attr("data-thumb");
    //Create the button
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.id = "b_" + thumb_id;
    element.type = "button";
    element.value = "Flip " + att_name;

    //Add button to page
    this.parentNode.appendChild(element);

    // create function for button.
    $("#b_" + thumb_id).on("click",function(e){  //need jQuery object, yet can't use $(this) for some reason. :-(
         e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //needed to stop form submission.
         //reset the <img> src attribute from the saved copy.
         var image = $("#invert"+thumb_id);
         image.attr("src",image.attr("data-url"));
         image.toggleClass("rotated"); //the bit that actually flips.. used to be so simple!
         image.wheelzoom();//Re-enable the zoom
    });
});
```

Why do I have to re-specify the selector inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$(this)` in your code refer to

```
$('.attached_preview')
```

so `$(this).on("click` fire when any element with class `.attached_preview` has been clicked

where as:

```
$("#b_" + thumb_id).on("click"
```

or:

```
$("#b_" + $(this).attr("data-thumb")).on("click"
```

fire click event for element with `id` named `#b_ + value of data-thumb attribute receive from your clicked .attached_preview`

Comment: The various $(this)/this/etc become confusing.. but I got there, you are correct, and explained better than my pithy response, have the tick Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I see it now, its because: `element != $(this)`.. gah.. Well, for posterity.